# AS3 change package name in whole project

Tags: actionscript-3, package

I have two projects (created with Flash IDE), which i'd like to merge. both use the default package and have a lot of classes, some of which conflict.

is there a easy way to change the package of a whole project from default to something specific?

Comment: A decent IDE (such as FDT, FlashDevelop or FlashBuilder) would allow you to use refactoring.  With the Flash IDE, I'm afraid there is no other way than search & replace.

Comment: You are asking for trouble if 1) you are using the Flash IDE to write ActionScript and 2) using a blank package name.

Comment: yeah I do know this now - won't use default package again. But Flash IDE IS great if you need to get a project done that is heavily graphics related and needs to be done in very short time. I often use Flash Builder, I like it a lot, but if i need to get a game done by hacking something together with extremely short deadline, I always go for Flash IDE.

Comment: @Mat You're aware that you can use multiple IDEs simultaneously for maximum effectiveness? i.e. use `Flash` for graphics and `FlashDevelop` for code.

Comment: You can use FlashDevelop and even Flash Builder in conjunction with the flash CS IDE. I typically use the CS IDE for doing all my designing, set up the document class and default project class directory and then create a FlashDevelop project in the same dir... and use it for coding.

Answer (score 0):

For IDE I use [FlashDevelop](http://flashdevelop.org), every time I move a Class to another folder it automatically renames the package inside the file, so I guess you can do that, create a flashdevelop as3 project, drag the folders with the sources, and move the Classes you need rename.